# Finding whether the field contains a class with required in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having a input field with a class = "required". Now I want to check in JQuery whether the field which is having the class as "required" contains value or not. If not like alerting..

I tried it with.

```
$("#ResultSubmit").submit(function(){

      if($("#"+<?=$r['Attribute']['id'];?>).fieldValue()=="")
      { 

                       alert("Fill in  "+"<?=$r['Attribute']['label'];?>");
                       $("#"+<?=$r['Attribute']['id'];?>).focus();
                       return false;
      }

     });
```

How to check if that contains a class with "required"?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [hasClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/hasClass)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("input.required").val() == "")
            alert("required")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#element input').attr('class') == 'required') {
    alert('required);
}
```

You could also get all required input fields like so

```
$('input[class=required]');
```

Of course, if you have multiple classes, you'll need to use the hasClass() method. This is recommend for future maintenance where you may decide you want 2 classes.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, so I modified my answer. I actually forgot about hasClass, and you reminded me. Have an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to solve your problem directly, rather than answer your question itself :)

```
$("#ResultSubmit").submit(function(){
  $("input.required").each(function() {
    var field = $(this);
    if ($.trim(field.val()) == '') {
      alert("Fill in " + field.prev('label').text());
      field.focus();
      return false;
  }
});
```

Register this code *once* on your page - not once per field. Make sure that all required fields have class `required` and that all required fields have a `<label>` element in from of them, containing the text that you wish to use in your error messages.

Voila - no more mixing client side and server side code! The javascript can even be in a seperate file.